# What is a SharePoint Developer Tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, spfx, office-365-developer

I have a tenant with a developer site collection in it. But it is not possible to upload an app with an .sppkg extension  to the 'App for SharePoint' page. There is no "New" option, neither an Upload link, that everyone else seems to have right here. The very fact I am getting here tells me I have an App Catalog, but I have never got at the "Create an App Catalog" option. I am instead routed to a page that suggests how to get going with my App Catalog site.
I have been told that it takes an "Developer Tenant" for this to work. What is the exact definition of a Developer Tenant? I just created a Developer site collection for a customer, exactly the way I did for my own stuff, and here the Create Catalog option comes up!
In my own tenant (not for the customer), I also have other site collections in parallel with my Developer Site, of Team type. Is that what breaks it? Do I need to remove those Site Collections that are not of Developer type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're developing new SPFx project for SharePoint, in this case, you need upload the .sppkg to tenant app catalog site instead of developer site.

You could find your tenant app catalog site in your tenant admin center.
[image]

Update:

Do you have enough permission?

Here is my screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for answer, but sadly of no help, at least for now. I am also getting there as you show me (so, I am probably at my app catalog site?). But when I click "App Catalog" I come
to a page "Get going with your App Catalog Site" (like you do, I believe). Here I can also click "Apps for SharePoint", 
and here is my problem because I can see no Upload or "New" option. 
Yes, I am developing SPFx project, just following the tutorial here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page.

Comment: Add comment for my previous reply.

Comment: I am admin and have full permission. But with Microsoft one never knows, so I will double-check. Some special permission for developing apps?
Yes, I am getting there. The whole first row (New Upload...) is gone for me. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi again!
Finally I solved it. I found that another guy who no longer work here, still was set as administrator for the app catalog site collection! Just put my name in there instead! Thank you for guiding me on the right track! It truly was a permission issue after all :-)